# Missing joint_state_publisher_gui when l run display.launch

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, ros-kinetic, gripper, universal-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a new urdf from original universal-robot package and a 2 finger robotiq gripper (from stl). URDF seems to be ok when i use the `check_urdf` command but when i try to see the urdf in rviz:

```
$roslaunch ur5_with_measurement_tool display.launch
```

I get this error

```
$Could not find the GUI, install the 'joint_state_publisher_gui' package
```

Which package would provide me this?

I installed ros melodic from apt
I installed universal_robot package and ur-robot-driver from git

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344992/missing-joint_state_publisher_gui-when-l-run-display.launch/) by [brodwix](https://answers.ros.org/users/51863/brodwix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A recent PR ([ros/joint_state_publisher#31](https://github.com/ros/joint_state_publisher/pull/31)) split the GUI parts of the JSP from the non-GUI parts.

This was done to avoid depending on GUI libraries in the non-GUI ROS metapackages (those defined in [REP-142](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0142.html) and [REP-150](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0150.html)). This facilitates deployments of ROS on robots, as it avoids pulling in all sorts of GUI libraries when they are not needed.

To fix the error you would have to make sure to install the `joint_state_publisher_gui` package. On Ubuntu/Debian (and other OS for which `.deb` packages are available and `apt` is used), you could do that with the following command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ros-<your_ros_version>-joint-state-publisher-gui
```

Make sure to replace `<your_ros_version>` with the code name of the ROS version you are using. So for Kinetic, replace it with `kinetic`. For Melodic, replace it with `melodic`.

The first command is to make sure you've downloaded up-to-date package indices.

The second command actually installs the package.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 16